# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' in converting a tuple to set

Tags: python, numpy

```
data_xy = tuple([x, y])
```

x and y are numpy arrays with sizes:
x.shape = (56567, 128, 16) and
y.shape = (56567, 1)

TypeError occurs in the following line:

```
    for data_class in sorted(set(data_xy[1])):
```

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: sets can’t contain mutable types. See  https://www.learnpython.dev/02-introduction-to-python/080-advanced-datatypes/50-sets/#set-s-can-t-contain-mutable-types

Comment: @balderman. Sets can contain mutable types just fine. They can't contain unhashable types.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hash a numpy array because it's mutable. Sets are hash tables that require all their elements to be hashable.

Since you can't apply `set` to the rows of an array, I suggest using `np.unique` instead:

```
s = np.unique(data_xy[1], axis=0)
s.sort()

for data_class in s:
```

In general, running a `for` loop over numpy arrays is something you should strive to work around, as its often unnecessary and slows things down.

An alternative solution would be to create a hashable wrapper type for the rows so you could use them in a `set`. This is going to be pretty slow and not recommended, but serves to illustrate the concept:

```
class RowView:
    def __init__(self, row):
        self.hash = hash(tuple(row))
        self.data = row
    def __hash__(self):
        return self.hash
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return np.argmax(np.less(self.data, other.data)) < np.argmax(np.less(other.data, self.data))

for data_class in (x.data for x in sorted(set(RowView(r) for r in data_xy[1]))):
```

A slightly faster solution that showcases custom hashing better is to extend `np.ndarray` with a custom hash. Then you can use the view objects directly without copying data forward and back:

```
class HashableArray(np.ndarray):
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple(self))
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return np.argmax(np.less(self, other)) < np.argmax(np.less(other, self))

for data_class in sorted(set(x.view(HashableArray) for x in data_xy[1]))):
```