# Adding array to set

Tags: python, numpy, set

Okay so my partner and I are working on the TSP problem, we generate a file, create and populate a matrix, and load it into a nparray.

Dataset

```
[[78 45 48 80 98]
 [73 83 22 83 37]
 [92 72 47 29 87]
 [86 64 17 58 70]
 [99 53 17 79 62]]

Expected output:
Starting city: [78, 45, 48, 80, 90]
index of next closest city(array([1], dytype=int64),) -- which is 45, closest distance otherwise the greedy algorithm

nextCity: [73, 83, 22, 83, 37]
index of next closest city(array([2], dytype=int64),) -- which is 22,
```

so on so forth, making sure that the indexes do not get checked twice. So in this case, array[1] and array[2] should be in a collection of sort that I can check if an array is in... like array[1] and array[2]. This way each 'city' is visited... so our theory is anyways. I've read through the methods for lists/dictionaries/sets and just can't seem to find something to fit my case, should I import a package?

I am trying to loop through the nparray, which is 2-D.
First, I start at cityMap[i]. In this case 0

```
for i in range(cityCount):
```

Then, I return the smallest value of the array at cityMap[i]

```
min = cityMap[i].min()
index = np.where(cityMap[i] == min)
```

I'm stuck because I need to add cityMap[i] to a set or sort of collection, and then check it for cityMap[index]

Then if cityMap[index] is in checkedCityCollection[], choose the next smallest index and so on... this way each cityMap[i] is only checked for the index of the small value once and only once.

Here is what Im working with

```
for i in range(cityCount):

    if cityMap[i] in checkedCitySet:
        #find index of next smallest value
    else:
        #Add city to checked cities
        checkedCitySet.add(cityMap[i])
        print(str(cityMap[i].min()))
        min = cityMap[i].min()
        index = np.where(cityMap[i] == min)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I'm stuck because I need to add cityMap[i] to a set or sort of collection, and then check it for cityMap[index]" - okay; so *why is this a problem*? You know how to create a set, yes? You know how to add elements to a set, yes? What happened when you tried writing that code? Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Also note that `min` is a function and assigning to it is a bad idea because you're shadowing the function.

Comment: Thank you, I've changed min to minDist. 
The error I receive:

if cityMap[i] in checkedCitySet: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

my set:

checkedCitySet = set()

I add the array to the city set like this
checkedCitySet.add(cityMap[i])

Comment: @sweeneyc22 Remember you can [edit] the post to add clarifications in a much neater manner.

Comment: As long as `cityMap[i]` is a numpy array, or even a Python list, you can't add it to a `set`.  It's just that simple.  How large is it?  You can convert it to a tuple, but if it's large that's going to add up pretty quickly.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64262955/typeerror-unhashable-type-numpy-ndarray-in-converting-a-tuple-to-set help?

Comment: Please provide a small, representative dataset for `cityMap` to help clarify your problem, and also give the output you're expecting for the example dataset. This really helps the community understand the problem and provide you with the help you need

Comment: you may find the numpy function `argmin` helpful, see [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html)

Comment: Thanks frederick, I will read into that. I will also update my post to include my dataset and expected output